# WSIT configuration file is loaded too many times

Tags: java, glassfish, wsit

I have a web service deployed on **Glassfish (v3.0.1)** application server. Today a number of visitors (around 300-400) visited our web page and our servers unfortunately went down. We are trying to identify the problem and fix it as soon as possible.

Our load tests with SoapUI was successfull and we do not understand what is the problem. There shouldn't be any problem for only 300 hundred users as we plan to serve to tens of thousands. When I check the server logs, I see the **WSIT** configuration file is loaded lots of times (thousands and more). I guess, everytime a user visits, this file is loaded. Is it normal to load it everytime (and see the message thousands time in the server log) or should it be loaded only once? Even if it should be loaded only once, does it ceate such a burden on the server so that nobody can login to page?

this is the complete message in the logs:

```
Loaded WSIT configuration from file: file:/home/appuser/glassfish-3.0.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/uupf2onyuz/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/wsit-client.xml.
```

I would appreciate any other suggestions for the cause of the breakdown of the server.

I am trying to edit the Glassfish settings. I have changed JVM settings and added the lines below:

> MaxPermSize=512m
>
> Xmx35g
>
> Xms32g
>
> Dsun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout=2
>
> Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=10

Also, I have changed the thread pool settings as such:

> Max Queue Size: 4096
>
> Max Thread Pool Size: 4000
>
> Min Thread Pool Size: 64
>
> Idle Thread Timeout: 900

Is it O.K. to have such configuration to handle many simultaneous thread or should I use different customization. I am trying to optimize Glassfish in order to handle many threads.

Comment: Have you identified the culprit? Glassfish vs database?

Comment: No, not yet but I am suspecting Glassfish because even tough there is no users around, we still have troubles accessing to web site...

Comment: In order to test the servers, we made a new deployment to another server and tested it with 30 users. The page was very fast and never broke down. This indicates that the actual server might have a bug or something. Any ideas?

Comment: I can only advice to keep testing with a higher workload, maybe some automation tool like selenium(http://seleniumhq.org/) might be useful.

Comment: Kinda found the problem. The main page is not coded with html and the weather service was not well-programmed which resulted as locking of the site completely. Now that we removed weather service, my load tests give me good results. Still, I am not sure whether it is normal to have too many WSIT files in the server log